# Perl application

Tags: mysql, perl

i was wondering if you can help me complete this application as i am finding it hard to complete it.
Basically i am trying to add/remove items dynamically using Linux Debian/Html/Perl/Mysql Database. I would really appreciate any help, even just hints on how to proceed. This is my code so far..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

print "Content-Type:text/html;\n\n";
print "<h1>Doctors Database</h1><br><br>";

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=doctors;host=localhost;port=3306";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "sal", "las"); 

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM persone');
$sth->execute;

print $sth->rows . " Doctors\n<br><br> ";

print "<form>";
print "Name:<br>";
print "<input type=text name=name><br>";
print "Age:<br>";
print "<input type=text name=age><br>";
print "<input type=submit value=add><br>";
print "<input type=submit value=remove><br>";
print "</form>";

print "<table cols=2 border=1>\n";

print "<tr>\n";
print "<th>Name</th>\n";
print "<th>Age</th>\n";
print "</tr>\n";

while (my $Data = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  print "<tr>\n";
  print "<td>", $Data->{'name'}, "</td>\n";
  print "<td>", $Data->{'age'}, "</td>\n";
  print "</tr>\n";
}

print "</table>\n";

$sth->finish;
```

Comment: can you explain what is missing or where you are struggling please.

Comment: It's really hard to help without knowing a lot more about what you're expected to know here.

Comment: hi there, thanks for getting back to me. Basically this code will simply display a mysql database i have created, in a table format. what i need is, be able to add/remove records to that database and automatically displaying them in my apache web server.

Comment: i would really appreciate any help here. thanks alot

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a CGI application. The CGI protocol is hard to deal with on your own. You'll need an interface to get your parameters into your program for adding and removing rows. Look at https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod as a start, but do also keep in mind that this is very old, out-dated technology. Your code is lacking a lot of basics for the HTML, so I assume you're not very familiar with web programming. You _can_ make subroutines to add and remove, but you need dispatch logic to call them as well.

Comment: @salvatore: You'll need to check the web server error log for more details of your error.

Comment: @salvatore: Well, as simbabque said, CGI is outdated technology and not really something you can pick up quickly. But [this course](http://ovid-cgi-course.perl-begin.org/cgi-course/) is a good way to get started. And I also recommend looking at [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).

Comment: thank you guys for your help. i will work on that

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
sub mysql_connect($$$$) {
    my ($database, $host, $user, $password) = (shift, shift, shift, shift);
    my $handler = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host", $user, $password, {RaiseError=>0,PrintError=>1});
    return $handler;
};

sub mysql_do($$) {
    my ($f_handler, $f_sql) = (shift, shift);
    my $f_statement = $f_handler->do($f_sql);
    my $error = $DBI::errstr;
    if(defined $error){
        return -1;
    };
    return ($f_statement);
};

sub mysql_prepare($$){
    my ($f_handler, $f_sql) = (shift, shift);
    my $f_statement = $f_handler->prepare($f_sql);
    my $f_response = $f_statement->execute();
    return ($f_statement, $f_response);
}

my $temp = "SELECT * FROM \`$database\`.\`$database_table\`";
print $temp."\n" if ($debug_mode == 1);
my ($statement, $response) = mysql_prepare($database_handler , $temp);

while (my $mysql_table_row = $statement->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    #do something with row as hash
}
```

Comment: will do thanks alot for taking the time. really appreciate it

Comment: If help is still needed, please let me know. But I think maybe you can handle the rest right now. You're welcome. :-)